# integrate Tinymce with dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Im using tinymce with image upload using the package "`laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload`". So I have a page where the user can select a registration type and enter some content in the tinymce textarea to associated that content to the selected registration type.

In the textarea the user can also upload images using the tinymce-simple-image-upload and this images are stored in "`~/projects/proj/public/img/image_15....`".

The content is stored in database in the certificates table in the column "content" like:

```
<p>certificate test<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GTrIzUnb.jpeg" 
   alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>
```

**Error:** The issue is that I have the code below to get a pdf with the certificate content associated with a specific registration and it works. But the downloaded pdf file, if the certifiate content has an image, the image dont appear in the pdf, in the pdf instead of show the image show this error "`Image not found or type unknown`".

Do you know why?

Code to get the certificate HTML from db in pdf:

```
public function getCertificateInfo($regID)
    {

        $participants = Participant::where('registration_id', $regID)
            ->whereHas('registration_type', function ($query) {
                $query->where('certificate_available', 'Y');
            })
            ->with('registration_type.certificate')
            ->get();

        $content = '';
        foreach ($participants as $participant) {
          $content .=
          '<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: always;">
                  '.$participant->registration_type->certificate->content.'</div>';
        }

        $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');

        $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/../../');

        $pdf->loadHTML($content);

        return $pdf->download('certificates.pdf');

    }
```

Like this with the html static it works, the image appears in the downloaded pdf:

```
  $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');


   $pdf->loadHTML('
    <p>cert1<img src="'.public_path().
    '/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" 
    alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>');


 return $pdf->download('certificates.pdf');
```

TinyMce code:

```
tinymce.init({
          selector:'textarea',
          plugins: 'image code link',
          relative_urls: true,

         file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            // trigger file upload form
            if (type == 'image') $('#formUpload input').click();
            }
});
```

The $content variable shows like:

```
"""
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: always;">\n
    <p>cert1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" 
    alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p></div> ▶
</div>
"""
```

Code in certificateController that inserts the certificate content (the content introduced in the tinymce textarea) in the DB:

```
 public function update(Request $request){

        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('id', $request->registrationType)->first();

        $certificate = $registrationType->certificate;

        // if no certificate exists for this type, create it
        if(!$certificate ) {
            $certificate = new Certificate();
        }

        // the certificate_content is the textarea with the tinymce plugin
        $certificate->content = $request->certificate_content;
        $certificate->save();

        $registrationType->certificate_id = $certificate->id;
        $registrationType->save();

        $certificateContent = RegistrationType::with('certificate')->where('id', $request->registrationType)->first();

        Session::flash('success','Certificate configured with success for the selected registration type.');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Comment: what is your folders structure? where is your application vs where your images are? why do you do `$pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/../../');` ?

Comment: The project is in "~/projects/proj". The images uploaded with tinymce are in "~/projects/proj/public/img/image_15....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/../../');
```

to:

```
$pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path());
```

and then you just need

```
$pdf->loadHTML('<p>cert1<img src="/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" 
alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>');
```

To get that point we need to know what is in:

```
$participant->registration_type->certificate->content
```

You have your content data stored like:

```
<p>certificate 1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>
```

To fix this issue you can update your data in database to change it to

```
<p>certificate 1<img src="img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>
```

Or you can transform content before converting it to pdf:

```
$content = str_replace('<img src="../../../','<img src="',$content);
$pdf->loadHTML($content);
```

I don't know why do you store img src with html - that is bad practice. And I don't know where else that data is in use. If this pdf generation is the only place you use that data - you can modify data in DB to keep your php code cleaner. But if you use that content somewhere else with some page widgets you will probably need to keep this data.

Comment: Thanks like that the $pdf shows the base path like "-basePath: "/Users/john/projects" and in the downloaded pdf still shows the error "Image not found or type unknown" instead of the image.

Comment: what do you expect to have instead of `"-basePath: "/Users/john/projects`?

Comment: Thanks but the code with static html like " $pdf->loadHTML('
    <p>cert1<img src="'.public_path().
    '/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" 
    alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>');" works. The issue is that the content is static but what is necessary is to actually use the html information stored in the database.

Comment: You wrote in OP *The $content variable shows like:* ... *<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg"* which to is not working. it should be full url to the image file.

Comment: So the issue is in the code that inserts the html in the database?

Comment: No the issue is that a link to image from PDF is broken. Valid link should be like `src="http://yourdomain.com/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg"`

Comment: The " $pdf->loadHTML($content);" loads the $content that is """"
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after:always;">\n<p>certificate 1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p></div> ▶"""" and in the database the certificate 1 content is "<p>certificate 1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>". But so using the setBasePath like "       $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/img/);" should work? The issue that dont works is because then is also necessary the image name?

Comment: The "$participant->registration_type->certificate->content" shows "<p>certificate 1<img src="../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>".

Comment: @John so can you get rid of `../../../` in your database and check for one particular record? so we need it to be `src="/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg"`

Comment: Thanks changing in the database to "<p>cert1<img src="img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>" the image appears in the pdf.

Comment: @John does it work for your project? do I need to provide `../..` remover code? or you are able to go forward yourself?

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying to in the db the content can stay like "../../../" and then remove that in the code?

Answer (score 0):

*You Must use the full server path.
to solve this you must replace the `../../../` to `projects/proj/public`
do like this.*

```
<?php str_replace('../../../','projects/proj/public',$content); ?>
```

*after that it loke like this.*

```
<img src="{{ public_path("projects/proj/public/img/".$ImageName) }}" alt="">
```